# Is a convervative and spherical symmetric vector field a radial vector field?

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields

In electrostatic, is well know that the *electric field* generated by point charged particle $q$ is given by:
$$\vec E(\vec r)=\kappa\frac{q}{||\vec r||^3}\vec r$$
This vector field is clearly conservative. This fact follows from its spherical symmetry (that is, $\vec E(\vec r)=\vec E(A\vec r)$ for any orthogonal matrix $A$) and its radial character ($\vec E(\vec r)=f(||\vec r||)\vec r$, for some function $f$).

My question is: *If $\vec E$ is a conservative vector field with spherical symmetry, then $\vec E$ must be a radial vector field*
$$\vec E(\vec r)=f(||\vec r||)\vec r \quad ?$$

Comment: I think you mean $A\circ \mathbf{E} = \mathbf{E}\circ A$ (that is $\mathbf{E}$ commutes with rotations)

Comment: You don't even need that the field is conservative.  Look up the "hairy ball theorem."  (Although this argument doesn't work in 2D.)

Comment: @peek-a-boo Does your definition imply that I can rotate the vector field around its center in any way I like and I will still have exactly the same vector field?

Comment: @DavidK yes, that's what it implies (let's note that OP's definition of simply $E = E\circ A$ for all $A$ is clearly false because even the identity function $\vec{r}\mapsto \vec{r}$ which we would intuitively like to regard as spherically symmetric doesn't satisfy this definition). If we think slightly more generally for the moment: let $M$ be a manifold and $X$ a vector field on $M$ and $\phi$ a diffeomorphism on $M$. Then, asking that the vector field $X$ remains unchanged by the "effect" of $\phi$ means we are requiring that the push-forward satisfies $\phi_*X = X$.

Comment: i.e $T\phi \circ X \circ \phi^{-1} = X$, where $T\phi:TM \to TM$ is the tangent mapping. The reason this "makes sense" is because if we initially are at a point $p$, we have a vector $X(p)$. After the effect of the transformation $\phi$, the point $p$ gets mapped to a new point $\phi(p)$, and there is already a vector $X(\phi(p))$ which was present there. But we want this to be such that if we "transport" the vector $X(p)$ to the point $\phi(p)$ via the tangent mapping, we want the two results to coincide; i.e $X(\phi(p))  = T\phi(X(p))$.

Comment: In the case $M$ is a linear space and $\phi$ is an invertible linear map $A$, this reduces (once we identify the various tangent spaces) to $A\circ E \circ A^{-1} = E$. Again, this should intuitively make sense because if we rotate ourselves from a point $p$ to a point $q$, then the vectors $E(p)$ and $E(q)$ should also coincide once we "pushforward" the vector $E(p)$ to the base point $q$. i.e $A(E(p)) = E(q) = E(A(p))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** I'm assuming we're working in $\mathbb R^3,$ since the electrostatic field is a three-dimensional field.
The following answer is written under that assumption, and does not necessarily work in spaces of other dimensions. In particular, if we were working in two dimensions then "spherically symmetric" is just "circularly symmetric" and the arguments below do not hold.

---

Never mind the conservative part. How can a vector field be spherically symmetric?

"Spherically symmetric" means that I can rotate the vector field around its center in any way I like and I will still have exactly the same vector field, exactly the same as if it had not rotated at all.

Now let's look at the field vector at some point at displacement $\vec r$ from the center of the spherical vector field,
and consider rotations of the spherical vector field around the axis through the origin and the chosen point, that is, rotations parallel to $\vec r$.

The field vector at that point must be unchanged by any such rotation.
What kind of vector can satisfy that property?

If the field vector is not parallel to $\vec r$ then a $180$-degree rotation (for example) will cause the field vector to point in a different direction.
The only way to keep the same direction is if the field vector is
parallel to $\vec r,$ that is, the field vector is a radial vector.

So there you have it. A spherically symmetric vector field is a radial vector field.

---

More formally, working from the definition that requires
$A\vec E(\vec r) = \vec E(A\vec r)$ for every orthogonal matrix $A$:

For a particular arbitrary displacement vector $\vec r,$
let $A$ be the matrix that performs a $180$-degree rotation about the axis parallel to $\vec r.$
Then $A\vec r = \vec r,$ hence $\vec E(A\vec r) = \vec E(\vec r).$
Spherical symmetry then requires that $A\vec E(\vec r) = \vec E(\vec r)$
for this particular choice of $A$ and $\vec r.$

Let $\hat r = \vec r/\lVert\vec r\rVert,$ that is, $\hat r$ is a unit vector parallel to $\vec r.$ Let $(\hat r, \hat u, \hat v)$ be an orthonormal basis.
Then $\vec E(\vec r) = x_1 \hat r + x_2\hat u + x_3\hat v$ for some real
$x_1,x_2,x_3.$ Since $A$ is a $180$-degree rotation about $\vec r$
(that is, about $\hat r,$)

$$ A\vec E(\vec r) = x_1 \hat r - x_2\hat u - x_3\hat v. $$

We conclude that

$$x_1 \hat r - x_2\hat u - x_3\hat v = x_1 \hat r + x_2\hat u + x_3\hat v,$$
which implies $-x_2 = x_2$ and $-x_3 = x_3,$
which is possible only if $x_2 = x_3 = 0.$

Therefore $\vec E(\vec r) = x_1\hat r,$ that is,
$\vec E(\vec r)$ is a radial vector.
Since the original choice of $\vec r$ was arbitrary,
the vector field $\vec E$ is a radial vector field.

---

Next we can compare the field vectors at two different points that are each at the same radial distance from the center of the vector field.
We rotate the vector field so that the first point is moved to the place where the second point was. This must not change the field vector. That tells us the field vectors had to have equal magnitude.
Since this is true for *any* two points at the same radial distance, all points at a given radial distance $r$ from the center of the vector field have field vectors of the same magnitude.
The radial distance $r$ determines the magnitude uniquely.

So now we know that a spherically symmetric vector field is a radial vector field in which the magnitude of the field vector at any point is a function of the radial distance $r$ from the center to that point.

From this it can be shown that the field is conservative.
That is, the phrase "conservative and spherically symmetric vector field" is redundant. If the vector field is spherically symmetric, we already know it is conservative without having to be told.

Comment: @MarkViola I don't think it is. Depending on which axis you choose for your spherical coordinates, you'll get different vectors in Cartesian coordinates. Or to put it another way, the field is preserved by rotation around your chosen axis, but not by rotation around any other axis.

Comment: You're getting stuck on one choice of spherical coordinates. Yes, the first field is symmetric around one particular axis, but that's not spherical symmetry. The second looks messy on the right hand side, but that's just showing that "spherical coordinates" are a bad way to describe spherical symmetry. Let me put it yet another way: where in the statement "$\vec E(\vec r)=\vec E(A\vec r)$ for any orthogonal matrix $A$" do you see anything about spherical coordinates?

Comment: Perhaps you could add a rigorous development that begins with the OP's definition.  One of the comments left by peek-a-boo suggested that the OP's definition was incomplete.  So, are you sure that the OP's definition is equivalent to the one suggested by peek-a-boo?

Comment: @MarkViola Hah! A point to you! I overlooked the error in the OP's definition.

Comment: I didn't realize we were keeping score.  :-).  But it would be interesting to see a rigorous development that begins with the "correct definition" (i.e., $A^T\cdot \vec E(\vec r)=\vec E(A\cdot \vec r)$) and then concludes with the conjectured result (i.e., $\vec E(\vec r)=\hat r(\hat r \cdot \vec E(|\vec r|))$).

Comment: @MarkViola OK, I have attempted to translate the original argument directly into peek-a-boo's notation. I'm not sure why you have $A^T$ instead of $A$ on the left, so I wrote $A\vec E(\vec r),$ but if that's wrong I think the argument still works since I chose a symmetric matrix.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that for every real finite-dimensional inner-product space $V$, a function $f:V\to V$ is spherically symmetric if and only if $f$ is radial [i.e for every orthogonal $A$, $A\circ f \circ A^{-1} = f$ if and only if there is a $g:[0,\infty)\to \Bbb{R}$ such that for all $v\in V$, $f(v)=g(\lVert v\rVert)\cdot v$]. The "if" part is obvious. In the case $\dim V=1$, the "only if" part is also pretty obvious. For $\dim V \geq 2$, we can easily adapt your proof.

Comment: @DavidK The expression should be $$\vec E(\vec r)=A\cdot \vec E(A^T\cdot \vec r)=A^T \cdot \vec E(A\cdot \vec r)$$since $AA^T=A^TA=I$So, yes.  The expression in the previous comment was a typographical error.  Good catch.